# How do I put multiple headings behind multiple columns of text?

Tags: css

Right now I have the data formatted as a table element. How do I make the headings go behind the data in each column, and have the headings be consistently off center from the text? Also, how do I align the heading right (note that the last character in the "Singles" and "Stats" headings line up vertically).

[This is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRs84.png)

The html of one of the tables goes something like this (I am using react):

```
    <table className="results-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h1 className="heading">Singles</h1>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h1 className="heading">a5</h1>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h1 className="heading">a12</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>34.23</td>
            <td>44.42</td>
            <td>23.34</td>
          </tr> ...
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Edit: I was able to modify Andrei Fedorov's solution to satisfy my constraints. If you have a simpler or better solution feel free to answer.

```css
th {
  font-size: 70px;

  color: var(--heading-color);
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--heading-color);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;

  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale3d(0.7, 1, 1) translate(-90%, 40%);
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: You need to include your code ... at least enough of your code for us to see what you've done and help you improve it. Please edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-size: 300%;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1rem .3rem;
}

th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: .3;
  transform: translate(0, 60%);
  color: #FFD18D;
  z-index: -1;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
  color: #B06868;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>qwe</th>
    <th>rty</th>
    <th>uio</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Notice I have two tables in the image, one under "Stats", and one under "Singles a5 a12". I need the two tables to be left aligned so that the tables line up. The headings of the two tables must line up, on the right side. The data of the two tables must line up, on the left side.

Comment: @okop Did I understand correctly that if I write full code for you, I get paid for you?

Comment: I apologize, I am somewhat new to stackoverflow so I do not know the appropriate questions to ask. I was able to modify your code to satisfy my constraints. Your answer is completely satisfactory for the question I asked.